# SQL Variable Changing Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, integer

I'm trying to rewrite the following code to use a variable instead of magic numbers:

```
SELECT tokenId, 
IIF(LEN(ref) < 4, ref, REPLICATE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),'*'), LEN(ref)-4) + SUBSTRING(ref, (LEN(ref)-3), LEN(ref))) as refMasked
FROM tokenBase
WHERE (refMasked is null or refMasked = '') AND ref is not null AND ref <> ''
```

I tried doing it like this:

```
DECLARE @NumberOfCharsAtEndOfStringToNotMask INTEGER
SET @NumberOfCharsAtEndOfStringToNotMask = 4 --Why do I need to set this to 2 for it to work?
SELECT tokenId, 
IIF(LEN(ref) < @NumberOfCharsAtEndOfStringToNotMask, ref, REPLICATE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),'*'), LEN(ref)-@NumberOfCharsAtEndOfStringToNotMask) + SUBSTRING(ref, (LEN(ref)-@NumberOfCharsAtEndOfStringToNotMask-1), LEN(ref))) as refMasked
FROM   tokenBase
WHERE  (refMasked is null or refMasked = '') AND ref is not null AND ref <> ''
```

However it doesn't work if I use `@NumberOfCharsAtEndOfStringToNotMask = 4`, I need to use 2 instead. Why is this?
If I use 4 then the last 6 chars of the string are left unmasked, however I need the last 4 chars to be unmasked. Using a value of 2 fixes this but I have no idea why.

**EDIT**
Amit has suggested I use the following code which works:

```
IIF(LEN(ref) < @NumberOfCharsAtEndOfStringToNotMask, ref,REPLICATE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),'*'), LEN(ref)-@NumberOfCharsAtEndOfStringToNotMask) + SUBSTRING(ref, (LEN(ref)-@NumberOfCharsAtEndOfStringToNotMask+1),@NumberOfCharsAtEndOfStringToNotMask)) as refMasked
```

Why does this work? Why can't I just replace the use of 4 with a variable storing the value of 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Dave:

```
DECLARE @C INTEGER = 4;

SELECT bpayreference 
     , LEN(bpayreference) As LengthOfString
     , LEN(bpayreference) - @C AS MinusC
     , SUBSTRING(bpayreference , (LEN(bpayreference) - @C) + 1 , (LEN(bpayreference) ) - (LEN(bpayreference) - @C))
     , CASE 
       WHEN (LEN(bpayreference) < @C) THEN REPLICATE('*' , LEN(bpayreference) - @C) 
       ELSE 
               REPLICATE('*' , LEN(bpayreference) - @C ) 
             + SUBSTRING(bpayreference , (LEN(bpayreference) - @C) + 1 , (LEN(bpayreference) ) - (LEN(bpayreference) - @C))
       END
FROM tokenbase
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `iif` block with this one and see how you go

```
IIF(LEN(ref) < @NumberOfCharsAtEndOfStringToNotMask, ref,REPLICATE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),'*'), LEN(ref)-@NumberOfCharsAtEndOfStringToNotMask) + SUBSTRING(ref, (LEN(ref)-@NumberOfCharsAtEndOfStringToNotMask+1),@NumberOfCharsAtEndOfStringToNotMask)) as refMasked
```

Comment: can you please explain why that works but mine doesn't?
Logically I'm just replacing 4 with a variable storing 4 aren't I?

Comment: Essentially your substring statement was incorrect. The starting position of the substring (i.e. the starting position of the string to keep) should be length of the string minus the characters to not mask + 1 (if the length of the string was 15 and characters to not mask are 4, then your substring should start from 15-4+1 = 12). Also, the last parameter to substring should be the number of characters to be included in it after the starting position. In this case it is `@NumberOfCharsAtEndOfStringToNotMask`. Hope that clarifies.